# Vector reserve causes memory leak

Tags: c++, vector, valgrind, capacity

I have a C++ app and I know in advance that I am expecting around 1000 elements (sometimes few more) to store and process for hundreds of instances.
The issue is that the memory used by the process increases slowly but the memory of the server is overwhelmed in few hours.
I am using valgrind for detecting eventual memory leaks.

**Edit**
First thanks to all of you for the suggestions. I managed to solve many errors. I added virtual destructors to some classes and changed some pointers to `boost::shared_ptr` using reset to delete them. However I still have an increasing memory usage over the time.

The main parts of the app are as follows :

```
#ifdef GLOBAL
#define Global
#else
#define Global extern
#endif
typedef std::map<uint32_t, ResultStruct> ClassDResultMap ;
typedef std::map<uint32_t, ClassDResultMap > ClassCResultMap ;
typedef std::map<uint32_t, ClassCResultMap > ClassBResultMap ;
typedef std::map<uint32_t, ClassBResultMap > ClassAResultMap ;
Global ClassAResultMap classAresultmap;
```

ClassZero creates many ClassA

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t,ClassA*> classAMap;
classA_[aid] = new ClassA(io_service_, filename.c_str(), id, pri_queue_);
```

Inside ClassA, up to 3200 ClassB instance are created:

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, boost::shared_ptr<ClassB >> classBMap ;
classBMap[aid].insert(std::pair<uint32_t, boost::shared_ptr<ClassB>>(bid, boost::make_shared<ClassB >(io_service_, pri_queue_, ...)));
```

Inside ClassB, up to 4 ClassC instances are created inside a ConfigMap struct having a member `boost::shared_ptr<ClassC > classC_;` :

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, classCConfig> ConfigMap;
(ConfigMap::iterator)->second.classC_ = boost::make_shared<ClassC >(io_service_, pri_queue_, ...);
```

Inside ClassC, one ClassD is instantiated by ClassC constructor

```
ClassC::ClassC(...): ClassD(io_service_, pri_queue_,...),... { }
```

Then Inside ClassD, elements are processed and results are calculated every 10-30 seconds than stored in ClassDResultMap :

```
(ClassDResultMap::iterator)->second[results.stime] = results;
```

Finally, inside another class, ClassStorage, all the results in the global ClassAResultmap are saved into files and cleared :

```
std::ofstream res_stream_;
res_stream_ << "{ \"start\" : " << results_it->second.stime << ...;
(ClassDResultMap::iterator)->second.clear();
std::map<uint32_t, ClassDResultMap>().swap((ClassDResultMap::iterator)->second);
```

This what I get with Valgrind with 1 Class A : 8 ClassB : 32 class C/D

```
==9544== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9544==     in use at exit: 25,817 bytes in 171 blocks
==9544==   total heap usage: 148,771 allocs, 148,600 frees, 16,803,272 bytes allocated
==9544== 
==9544== 1,216 bytes in 4 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 39 of 45
==9544==    at 0x4C2677B: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==9544==    by 0x40118A2: _dl_allocate_tls (in /lib64/ld-2.12.so)
==9544==    by 0x5F971E8: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==9544==    by 0x4E3ACC0: boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept() (in /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0)
==9544==    by 0x45EE92: boost::thread::start_thread() (thread.hpp:180)
==9544==    by 0x461429: boost::thread::thread<boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned long, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned long, boost::asio::io_service>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::io_service> > >&>(boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned long, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned long, boost::asio::io_service>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::io_service> > >&) (thread.hpp:267)
==9544==    by 0x4605F7: boost::thread* boost::thread_group::create_thread<boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned long, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned long, boost::asio::io_service>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::io_service> > > >(boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned long, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned long, boost::asio::io_service>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::io_service> > >) (thread_group.hpp:78)
==9544==    by 0x45CAC9: main (main.cpp:151)
==9544== 
==9544== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9544==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9544==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9544==      possibly lost: 1,216 bytes in 4 blocks
==9544==    still reachable: 24,601 bytes in 167 blocks
==9544==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9544== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==9544== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==9544== 
==9544== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9544== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

and the part of main.cpp which Valgrind complains about :

```
boost::asio::io_service work_io_service;
ClassZero manager(work_io_service);
boost::thread_group work_threads;
uint32_t workers = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != workers; ++i)
{
    work_threads.create_thread(
    boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, boost::ref(work_io_service)));
}
```

My issue is that in almost 20 minutes, the server memory (4GB ) increased from 3% to 17% and keeps going on. The process memory usage is increasing but stays below 4% !

Comment: If you comment out the `reserve` calls do you still get a memory leak ?

Comment: What happens if you [copy the vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/) instead of swapping it?  (Your vectors are small, so the performance should be negligible.)

Comment: Are you deleting your 8 original vectors (`seq0_set`, ....)?  `64128/8 = 8016 = 8 * 1002`.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Without one, this  will devolve into a pointless guessing game I fear.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the vectors that you posted.  They are vectors of integers -- absolutely no issue should be found with them as these do not leak memory.  If it were a vector of pointers to dymamically allocated memory, then that may be an issue, but isn't the case here.  What may be the problem is that some other part of your code, possibly the object that is containing these vectors, is not deallocated.

Comment: `Then in the class constructor`  You better show this class and how you instantiate it.  If it's with `new`, then that could be the issue.  Similarly, if the object is derived from a base class, and the base class does not have a virtual destructor, then that could be another issue.  My crystal ball is telling me these things, so you really do need to post the code.

Comment: To repeat @BaummitAugen : Keep ripping out parts of your code until either (a) the problem goes away or (b) the remainder is small enough to post as a complete self-contained example.

Comment: To the OP:  See this example and run it through valgrind (I do not have valgrind handy):  http://ideone.com/EwlX9X  If you get similar results, then this demonstrates how a lack of a virtual destructor can cause issues like this.

Comment: I do get issues when I comment reserver, Valgrind points to push_back.
No I use clear after processing elements and before swapping between them, so that the ones storing new elements are empty.

Comment: I am using new to instantiate the class where the vectors belong. I can not provide an SSCCE because it is a very complex app. Class A creating new instances of a Class B, each B creating new instances of C, each C creating 4 instances of D, and vectors belong to D.

Comment: I implemented a destructor for each class but I do not know what is the difference with a "virtual" destructor ? When the app finishes the work (it is a service and does not stop), the memory drops to the initial values so I guess everything is freed properly. The issue is when it runs for hours, the server memory is completely used ...

Comment: @Mils `I am using new to instantiate the class where the vectors belong`  So maybe that's the issue -- you are not calling `delete` on one or more instances of this class.  I think you're not looking at the real problem -- again, a `vector<some_int>` is not going to leak memory.  What *is* going to leak memory is if you have an object (created with `new`) that doesn't get deallocated that contains these vectors.  The error would be pointing to the vector leakage since those vectors never had a chance to have their respective destructors called (since the parent object was never destroyed).

Comment: @Mils `I implemented a destructor for each class but I do not know what is the difference with a "virtual" destructor ? `  If the destructor is not virtual, and you delete an object through a base class pointer, the behavior is undefined.   Usually what happens is that the derived object never gets cleaned up, only the base class.  That's what the program I linked to shows you -- that program leaks memory.  So do your classes have virtual destructors?  If not, do you create instances of the derived objects using a base class pointer?  If you are creating them, then that may explain your leak.